# how to display postgres table as html table using node js

Tags: html, node.js, postgresql

So I have been wanting to know how to display a database table from Postgres into a html table on a web-page dynamically. I've tried using EJS and pug templates but I have found function/parameter not defined error in both of them. heres the code

the server side

```
app.get("/balance.ejs",(req,res)=>{ 
pool.query("SELECT * FROM accounts",function(err,result){
    if (err) throw error

res.render('balance',{data:result});
});
```

});

the html side

```
<table border="4" id="tab">
<thead>
  <tr><b>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Balance</th>
    
  </tr></b>
<tr>
  <% data.forEach(entry => { %>
    <td><%= entry.name %></td>
    <td><%= entry.balance %></td>
</tr>
<% }) %>
</thead>
```

Here im getting the error "data.forEach is not a function"

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically? Are you wanting it to update to show new data? There's a lot that you're missing here, and you need to at least attempt this before asking a question here. Everyone else on this site will tear you apart because you appear to be asking us to spoon-feed you code. This may not be the best way to learn how to do this.

Comment: yes i meant it to be updated as the table in database get updated. Also as i have said i have tried a few ways but couldnt get anywhere. I wanted to put in the code i tried but the code is kind of big and the code in question is only a part of the big program. Still i will try to put in the code in the OP

Comment: It's also acceptable if you could link to a GitHub repo with your code. I'd be happy to take a look if you could do that. Also, if you want the HTML page to update in real-time, just know that you'll need an internal loop to constantly query the database. Also, you're going to need a reactive framework or you'll have to write some really complex JavaScript

Comment: ive already edited the post with the part of the code that ive tried. If you can  have a look

Comment: Awesome, can you console log what data is and post the result? if data isn't an array, then you won't be able to iterate over it. Let's see what it outputs

Comment: Oh it just shows "ReferenceError: data is not defined" . I think we know the problem. Now we only need to pass the content in the table as a string in 'data' right?

Comment: Not as a string. Whatever value you assign to data must be an array to iterate over it as you show. Then the values in the array should be objects of table data.

Comment: yes i absolutely get what your saying. Now i only need help implementing this.  Would that be a stretch

Comment: How about this. You git it your best shot, and if you still can't get it to work I'll point you in the right direction

Comment: I will do so but i thought we already passed the array of the table to 'result' in this line " pool.query("SELECT * FROM accounts",function(err,result){" and then to 'data' while rendering as "res.render('balance',{data:result});"

Comment: oh i just did it . i realized i did not have any object for the data so i  put in " { data:result.rows } " . Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I had missing object so I put in:

```
{
  data: results.rows
}
```

It worked